# Grid component for ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, grid, datatables, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to display a grid on a web page. I have ASP.NET MVC 4 as backend. I have some additional requirements.

1. Component must be scalable. I.e. now I need a simple read-only grid, but in the future may be necessary to add editing, grouping, etc.
2. Component must be friendly to [Minification and Bundling ASP.NET MVC 4 mechanism](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/11/27/new-bundling-and-minification-support-asp-net-4-5-series.aspx).

In other words, the component should consist of modules, which can be added for improving functionality. My project uses jQuery UI as centralized UI theme management tool. So I think about jqGrid or DataTables. Perhaps there are other solutions, which I do not know.

Which component/solution should I use in my situation?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can use almost any JavaScript grid library with ASP.NET MVC 4.0. It should just corresponds your other requirements.

For example you can use jqGrid and include jqGrid [modules](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ahow_to_install#development_installation) instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` or `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`. An additional advantage of the approach is that you can use *the latest version* of jqGrid from [github](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid) and be able more quickly implement bug fixes. So you can include at the beginning

```
i18n/grid.locale-en.js
grid.base.js
grid.common.js
jquery.fmatter.js
```

Some more files can be needed only if you would use some [additional jqGrid functionality](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajquery_ui_methods):

```
jqDnR.js
jqModal.js
grid.jqueryui.js
```

Later, if you decide to implement data filtering or searching, you can include additional modules

```
grid.custom.js
```

for [the toolbar filtering](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atoolbar_searching) or

```
grid.formedit.js
grid.filter.js
```

in case of [single field searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asinge_searching) or [advanced searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aadvanced_searching).

If you later decide implement grouping, tree grids, subgrids or one from tree supported editing mode you will need just append the list of included modules.

Answer (score 0):

Kendo UI from Telerik is a promising component library for HTML 5 components. They have a web grid which performs very well and works with ASP.Net MVC 4 minification as well:

http://demos.kendoui.com/beta/web/grid/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC. I am using most of the components in the suite with an MVC4 project I am working on.

I am not using the bundling features of MVC 4, instead I am using the Combres package.